# Set Text to Integer Value

Tags: android, textview, integer

I want to set a `TextView` as the value of an integer, hopefully like so:

```
tv.setText(int)
```

I tried this an I get this error.

Also, my integer value is in another class

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.application, PID: 29603
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4427)
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Generally,

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(int));
```

If the value is inside another class? You can make a getter for the value you want in that class:

```
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

So that you can access it from the other one:

**BUT** if you set a TextView to an int, it will be interpreted as an Android *resource id*. If you want the value of the int as your text (and not the resource it points to), make it a String first.

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(theOtherClassInstance.getValue()));
```

**EDIT** If your int is `firstResult` as per your comment below, then the getter becomes:

```
public int getFirstResult() {
    return firstResult;
}
```

Comment: so in this case, the integer is "firstResult", would I set "public int getValue() {" to public int getValue(firstResult) {:?

Comment: No, you don't need to pass any information in to getValue() - it returns one integer and one integer only. So you just need getValue() :)

Comment: how does it know the value of my integer then?

Comment: There are a couple of errors, one with int: "Syntax error on token "int", @ expected" and another with the closing bracket: "Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement"

Comment: I modified the answer with the name of your int

Comment: tv.setText(String.valueOf(theOtherClassInstance.getValue())); works! +1

Answer (score 24):

Doing setText(int) you are refering to an application resource from the XML files, not the value itself.

To set the integer propertly do the following:

```
tv.setText(""+integer);
```

or better solution:

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
```