# how to settext of android textview to Integer

Tags: android, textview, database-cursor

I used to set text of my text view the count of my database rows. but it gives me an error. what should i do?

In My Handler Method:

```
    public Integer METHOD_NAME(){

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE", null);

        Integer first=c.getCount();
        return first;

}
```

In My Activity Code:

```
    int COUNT=db.METHOD_NAME();
    db.open();
    MyTEXTVIEW.setText(COUNT);

    db.close();/* what is my Codes problem?
```

How to make it without problem? */

While i set the text of text view to a String, it doesn't show me any errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Text to Integer Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781535/set-text-to-integer-value)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should call the db.open() befor making a query as pointed by user370305 Secondly your **METHOD_NAME()** returns an **Integer** where as your COUNT  variable is an **int** .
So you can do 
**int COUNT=db.METHOD_NAME().intValue()**
Or change the return type of **METHOD_NAME()** type entirely to **int**

Comment: Thanks for answering. i got my answer

Answer (score 1):

Convert `int` into `String`,

```
MyTEXTVIEW.setText(String.valueOf(COUNT));
```

Actually `setText()` only accept int as resource when your string resource is declared in `string.xml` file.

**Update:** I also doubt your code, you have `db.open()` method call after `db.METHOD_NAME();`, so if `db.open()` is for opening database connection than you have to change the sequence of both statements.

Like,

```
db.open();
int COUNT=db.METHOD_NAME();
MyTEXTVIEW.setText(COUNT);
db.close();/* what is my Codes problem?
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT I WISH YOU SUCCES

Comment: Just I Can Say THANKS!