# .setText giving fatal exception

Tags: android

while using the given method in [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC0zg.png) I am getting a fatal exception at the line of .setText but overall Log.d is working properly

Comment: Convert your Int to a String because the `setText(int i)` is used for string resource `e.g. setText(R.string.title)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Text to Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781535/set-text-to-integer-value)

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setText()` accepts `String` and you are passing `int`