# App crashes when trying to dynamically change the textView's text in a Bottom App Bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to dynamically change the text of a `textView` placed within a `BottomAppBar` ,but this causes my app to crash. The number of items of the recyclerview which are selected are to be displayed in the `textView`. This is done in the `updateViewCounter()`. Everything works fine when the number of selected items are displayed with a `Toast`.
Here's my code:

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<ImageModel > imageList;
    ArrayList<ImageModel> selectedList;
    TextView selected_text;
    RecyclerView imageRecyclerView;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    View view;
 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
        runtimePermission();
 
        return view;
    }
 
 
 
    private void runtimePermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(getContext()).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        init();
                        getAllImages();
                        setImageList();
 
                    }
 
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission is Required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
 
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
 
    public void init() {
        imageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.photos_recycler);
        selected_text = view.findViewById(R.id.selected_textView);
        imageList = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
 
    }
 
 
    public void setImageList() {
        imageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager((new  GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4)));
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(), imageList);
        imageRecyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
 
        imageAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemViewClick(int position, View v){
                try {
                    if (!imageList.get(position).isSelected) {
                        selectImage(position);
                    } else {
                        unSelectImage(position);
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ed) {
                    ed.printStackTrace();
                }
 
            }
 
 
        });
    };
 
    public void selectImage(int position) {
        imageList.get(position).setSelected(true);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        prepareSelection(position);
    }
 
    public void prepareSelection(int position) {
 
        if (!selectedList.contains(imageList.get(position))) {
            selectedList.add(imageList.get(position));
        } else {
            selectedList.remove(imageList.get(position));
        }
 
        updateViewCounter();
    }
 
    public void unSelectImage(int position) {
        imageList.get(position).setSelected(false);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        prepareSelection(position);
    }
 
    private void updateViewCounter() {
        int counter = selectedList.size();
        selected_text.setText(valueOf(counter));
    }
 
 
    public void getAllImages(){// queries mediastore }
}
```

And here's the `activity_main.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"  >
 
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
 
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
 
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:tintMode="@color/white"
                android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
                app:fabSize="auto"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
                app:fabAlignmentMode="end" />
 
 
            <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
                app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar_menu">
 
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selected_textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="selected"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"/>
 
                </RelativeLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
     app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Text to Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781535/set-text-to-integer-value)

Comment: Also, please include the actual error stacktrace in case this is not the issue you're facing.